# Error when passing audio file into watson websocket: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2341)

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to identify uses of 'manager', 'warranty', and 'replace' in an audio file using the watson speech to text api. The error I get back is cryptic:

Error received: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2341)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    iam_apikey="__nunya__",
    url="__nunya__"
)

class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

    def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        print('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

myRecognizeCallback = MyRecognizeCallback()

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'AudioRecordings/ComputerSupportCall.mp3'),
              'rb') as audio_file:
    audio_source = AudioSource(audio_file)
    speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(
        audio=audio_source,
        content_type='audio/mp3',
        recognize_callback=myRecognizeCallback,
        model='en-US_BroadbandModel',
        keywords=['manager', 'warranty', 'replace'],
        keywords_threshold=0.5,
        max_alternatives=3)
```

What I'm trying to get back is a response in this format:

```
      "keywords_result": {
        "manager": [
          {
            "normalized_text": "manager",
            "start_time": 1.52,
            "end_time": 2.15,
            "confidence": 0.978
          }
        ], (etc ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course I found the answer right after posting ... the file path was incorrect, should have been:

```
with open(join(dirname(__file__), 'AudioRecordings/ComputerSupportCall.mp3')
              'rb') as audio_file:
```